# Angularjs: is this way of writing wrong?

Tags: angularjs, binding, angular-ng-if, angularjs-ng-init

```
<input ng-model="search" type="text">
<table ng-if="search.length > 2 || search.length == 0" 
       ng-init="somerows = getdata()">
   <tr ng-repeat="row in somerows | filter:search">...</tr>
</table>
```

some times it results faster thinking this *visual way
but is this wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `ng-init` only gets executed when the element is compiled, so your `getdata()` will only get called when the table appears.  Here's what happens as you type:

1. Blank `search`: table is displayed, `getdata()` called
2. Type 'a': table is hidden, `getdata()` NOT called
3. Type 'b': table is still hidden, `getdata()` NOT called
4. Type 'c': table is displayed, `getdata()` is called
5. Type 'd': table is still displayed so `getdata()` is NOT called
6. And so on, `ng-init` will not be executed until the table is hidden again and re-displayed by the `ng-if`

If you have 10 characters and CTRL+X to cut them, your search term is blank but `getdata()` still isn't called because the table is still displayed and ng-init is not executed.  If you paste something in then `getdata()` still isn't called because the table is visible and `ng-init` has already been executed.

I think it would be better to watch the search term and call `getdata()` then:

```
$scope.$watch('search', function(newValue) {
    if (typeof(newValue) === "string" && 
              (newValue.length == 0 || newValue.length > 2)) {
        $scope.getdata();
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out [***this plnkr***](http://plnkr.co/edit/PGHIDrcY6a24QjOtLvj4?p=preview).  The ng-init is called when the if adds or removes the element, but if you start typing it is only called when you hit the third character and not after.

Comment: Just to add, `ng-if` actually adds or removes the associated DOM object and is the reason why `ng-init` isn't executed until the 3rd character since it doesn't actually exist yet.